# Join on max value if join condition not met

Tags: sql-server, join

I am trying to calculate how much vacation time an employee would have based on the amount of time he worked.

employeeVacation -> id, yearsWorked, vacationHours

employee -> empid, StartDate

I can get the number of years the employee worked by using this

```
datepart(year, getdate()) - datepart(year,StartDate) as yearsWorked
```

After you work for more that 8 years the vacation time is the same. Here is my vacation table.

```
id years vacationHours
1   0   40
2   1   40
3   2   40
4   3   80
5   4   80
6   5   80
7   6   80
8   7   120

select e.empid, ev.vacationhours from employee e join employeevacation ev on
ev.yearsWorked = datepart(year, getdate()) - datepart(year,e.StartDate)
```

So say you work for 30 years I can't do a join to get the number of vacation hours. Should I be looking to do a join, or should I just cut my losses and insert years into the vacation table up to like 100 so that way I can join and not worry about it.

Comment: Be careful here. If you have an employee who started in December and you run this the next January (which could be only a couple days) you will return 1 as the number of years worked when it hasn't even been over a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT e.empid, ISNULL(ev.vacationhour, 0)
FROM employee e 
LEFT JOIN employeevacation ev ON ev.yearsWorked = (
    SELECT MAX(ev2.yearsWorked) 
    FROM employeevacation ev2 
    WHERE yearsWorked<=datepart(year, getdate()) - datepart(year,e.StartDate)
)
```

Basically, you query the highest threshold he is eligible to.

You can replace 0 with whatever default value you may want. Although you should never hit the default value if you have an employeevacantion row with 0 years.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
select e.empid, coalesce(ev.vacationhours, evMax.vacationhours)
from employee e 
    left join employeevacation ev on ev.yearsWorked = datepart(year, getdate()) - datepart(year,e.StartDate) 
    join employeevacation evMax on evMax.yearsWorked = 7
```